# Getting real size of element in Selenium

Tags: css, selenium, size

I'm using Selenium to test the application.
One of the tests is to verify change of element's size.

I know about WebElement's getSize method.
Problem is when CSS3 transform is applied, specifically scale.
Then Selenium's getSize doesn't return real size of element, but size it would have with scale 1.

But application takes advantage of CSS3, so I need to get real size including scaling.

Is it possible?

Tnanks for any inputs.